# Three.JS Running at modal (pop-up) window

Tags: three.js, popup, bootstrap-modal, gallery

I have a simple CSS image gallery and when you'are clicking on any image, the script opens a new modal (pop-up) windows with THREE.JS scene, which is basically built on image data.

The problem is that every time you open next image, everything becomes slow and slow—the script doesn't kill previous scenes and its data.

By code looks like this (JQuery) :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#modalClose").click(function(e) { $("#modalThree").css("display","none"); $( "#group" ).show(); $( "#container").empty(); while(scene.children.length > 0){ scene.remove(scene.children[0]); } });

        var gallerySize = 6;

            for(var i = 1; i <= gallerySize; i++){

                $("#0" + i).click(function(e) { 

                    $("#modalThree").css("display","block");

                    $( "#group" ).hide();

                          loader.load(

                             $(this).attr("src") ,

                             function ( texture ) { init(texture);  },
                             function ( xhr ) { },
                             function ( xhr ) { }

                          );

                    } );    

            }

});
```

Pretty sure that I need to 'kill' all variables, objects, geometries, but don't know how and it would be great if someone here could help me. Please.

Answer (score 0):

In your example scene is cleared on dom ready, not on on click event.

Try this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var gallerySize = 6;

        for(var i = 1; i <= gallerySize; i++){            

            $("#0" + i).click(function(e) { 
                while(scene.children.length > 0){ scene.remove(scene.children[0]); }
                $("#modalThree").css("display","block");

                $( "#group" ).hide();

                      loader.load(

                         $(this).attr("src") ,

                         function ( texture ) { init(texture);  },
                         function ( xhr ) { },
                         function ( xhr ) { }

                      );

                } );    

        }

});
```

Comment: Not really, it's at the pop-up "close" event. Posted slightly wrong version.

Comment: Try also 'scene = null'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, lagging happens because of growing # of listeners.

[image]

And performance stats show that there are 34, then 43, 46, 53, 56, 61, 64 and so on...